# MySQL Error 1048 + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE + COALESCE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm getting into something very intriguing with MySQL. I have an automated process to insert / update data into a table.
The table has 4 columns (the first 2 make the primary key) and the third is a non nullable varchar. The last column is a bigint
My query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES('a', 'b', null, 100) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3=COALESCE(VALUES(col3), col3), col4=COALESCE(VALUES(col4), col4)
```

So in theory, the row with the primary key ('a','b') won't have its col3 value changed but col4 should get the value 100.

But since the col3 is not nullable I get the error: "Error Code: 1048. Column 'col3' cannot be null".

Did I get something wrong about the ON DUPLICATE KEY ? How can I achieve this update ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

FYI:
MySQL : v5.7
Engine: InnoDB

Comment: When you write *I get an error*, the very next thing that follows should be the **exact, complete error message** that you're seeing. It's on the screen right  in front of you, but we can't see your screen from here. The message contains more information than simply *1048 error*, and that additional information is meaningful. Please [edit] your post to include that message content.

Comment: I guess you are right even though you said it in kind of a mean way and even if a 1048 MySQL error is a very "known error" and unique:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-error-reference.html

Comment: I didn't say anything in any *mean way*. I mentioned that you had not provided relevant information. We should not have to google error codes when you have that information right in front of you. You're asking us for free help to solve your problem, and making it as easy as possible for us to do so is in your best interest. I could have just downvoted the question for not having the relevant content and moved on, but I explained the problem instead and gave you an opportunity to fix it. You should learn to accept constructive advice from users who are more experienced here that try to help.

Comment: With the error text you've now added, it's clear to see that the issue is with `INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('a', 'b', **null**, 100)`, because the error message clearly says **Column `col3` cannot be null**, and your INSERT statement very clearly assigns **null** as the value for `col3`. When you define a column as not allowing `null`, then you can't try to assign a `null` value to that column. See what benefit the **specifc error message** provided that your original version did not?

Comment: COALESCE(VALUES(col3), col3) is supposed to avoid the null and keep the value already existing in the row

Comment: No, the COALESCE will only be reached if the row is a duplicate, and you don't have an existing row that is a duplicate with a NULL value for col3. Therefore, the INSERT is attempted, and it fails because you can't set col3 to `null` (just as the error message explains).

Comment: Oh ! Okey so actually the values are checked before even attempting the insert and moreover before reaching the on duplicate key update ! Well that makes it clear. Thank you for your help. You can write an answer if you wish i will accept it.

Comment: Not quite. The INSERT is attempted, the attempt at assigning to col3 occurs, and the error is raised. The ON DUPLICATE will only happen if the INSERT fails because a duplicate row exists, but it never gets that far because of the invalid col3 assignment attempt.